# Normalisation vs Performace: benefit/issues of removing linking tables in (this) schema?

Tags: mysql, performance

Generally i like to keep my database as clean and expandable as possible.

However after doing some tests, I realised that whilst this is usually the best way to do it, when dealing with large datasets its a lot slower than what i refer to as the "dirty" approach to the problem.

Basically lets say i have a table of objects. These objects belong to certain people. One object may have one person, whilst others more than 1. My initial thought was as I always do, create an objects table for my objects, a peoples table for my people, and then a object_to_people linker table.

However joining the object and linker table in order to get all objects a person is assigned to, can take up to 3 seconds (that's based on around 400k records, but only 1 link per object). Yes i also set up index's e.c.t. to try and speed things up.

If I instead remove the people and linker table, and put the people in the objects table as columns and use 1/0 to set whether each person is assigned to that object, without joining the two large tables i see a speed of around 0.3 -> 0.7 seconds (varied greatly).

To begin with, we only need 2 people. But I don't want to be too restrictive if i can help it. I know I can use caching and what not to improve the end user timings, but is there any reason this would be considered a really bad idea to use columns rather than link tables?

Comment: Little pictures go a long way in schema-related questions.

Comment: Normalize. The only time to add separate "category" columns is if the list of "categories" is well understood and limited. In your case, you expect the list of people to grow - you will pay for the decision not to normalize - I promise :-)

Comment: Here is a good read on [Normalization](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal.html)

Comment: @drdwilcox But that doesn't address the performance issue -- what can be done to speed up the normalized form (or to make queries, possibly with less ACID requirements, faster)?

Comment: There's always a trade-off when denormalizing: reads (SELECT) can be sped up, but writes (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) tend to slow down (because you generally need to enforce more constraints). Whether to denormalize depends in part on the balance between reads and writes in your application. Too bad MySQL doesn't support indexed views (a.k.a. materialized views).

Comment: Inserting isnt really a problem. The "People" table would be updated very rarely. I estimate, that after the website goes live. There would be only 2 rounds of updates and insertions over the next year. As for the objects table, that may grow rapidly to be begin with, but as it fills, the less quickly we will be entering data. And anything other than a SELECT is all administrative end. I may stick with my usual linker table and see what happens. I guess the whole point of a full solution is that everything in that solution plays a part (caching e.c.t). Cheers for the replies

Comment: @pst. That's true. I should have mentioned indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar setup.
My join table has 17,000,000 rows. My "person" table has 8,400,000 rows, and my "objects" table has 300,000 rows.

I have queries with multiple joins on my joins table and unions of results that return tens of thousands of rows and they take less than 1 second to run (50-400ms).

I think your first layout could be fine, but you probably need to focus on your indexes and queries.

Answer (score 0):

> but is there any reason this would be considered a really bad idea to
>   use columns rather than link tables?

I would say it is a really *bad* idea if you value scalability more than the performance you gained.

I would say it is a really *good* idea if you value the performance you gained more than scalability.

Answer (score 0):

if it is true that one object can simultaneously belong to more than one person... then keep the link table.

Answer (score 0):

Also in mysql `alter table` on huge tables can execute extremely long so adding new users in an application won't be possible in reasonable time.